# How to update a Rails 3 project to latest gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a new Ruby on Rails 3.0.1 project, and then globally updated gems to 3.0.3.

After some digging around, I ended up editing the project Gemfile to say "3.0.3" instead of "3.0.1", and then ran "rake rails:update", and now it appears that everything is up-to-date.

However, I can't find any references on the Internet for doing this with Rails 3, so I want to make sure this is the right way of doing things. Confirmation appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're changing the version in your Gemfile, you should be running `bundle update` so that all gems are updated to their latest versions specified by the `Gemfile`. `rake rails:update` is used for updating things such as the Prototype assets to the latest version.

Comment: Is that a change from Rails 2? I'm new to Rails, but it seems like the Rails 2 method was to update the RAILS_GEM_VERSION variable and then run rake rails:update.

Comment: @drinian: Rails gem management is now taken care of by Bundler. The Gemfile is your one-stop-shop for all gem versioning.